# Troubles with the following trigonometric identity

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove the following trigonometric identity, but I can't.

$$\coth\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) = \frac{\sinh x - i\sin y}{\cosh x-\cos y}$$

Here $z=x+iy$. I tried the following

$$\coth\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) = \frac{\cosh\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{\sinh\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)} = \frac{\cosh^2\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{\sinh\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\cosh\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)} = \frac{1+\cosh z}{\sinh z} = \frac{1 + \cosh x\cos y + i\sinh y\sin x}{\sinh x\cos y + i\cosh x\sin y}$$

I don't know if this is the correct way to do the problem or how to continue from here. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: If what you have done is correct, the next step that I would take would be to multiply top and bottom of your rational expression by complex conjugate of the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w=z/2 = u+iv$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\coth(z/2)&=\coth(w)\\\\
&=\coth(u+iv)\\\\
&=\frac{\cosh(u+iv)}{\sinh(u+iv)}\\\\
&=\frac{\cosh(u)\cos(v)+i\sinh(u)\sin(v)}{\sinh(u)\cos(v)+i\cosh(u)\sin(v)}\\\\
&=\frac{\cosh(x/2)\cos(y/2)+i\sinh(x/2)\sin(y/2)}{\sinh(x/2)\cos(y/2)+i\cosh(x/2)\sin(y/2)}\\\\
&=\frac{ \sinh(x/2)\cosh(x/2)-i\sin(y/2)\cos(y/2)}{\cosh^2(x/2)-\cos^2(y/2)}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac12 \sinh(x)-i\frac12 \sin(y)}{\frac12 \cosh(x)-\frac12 \cos(y)}\\\\
&=\frac{\sinh(x)-i\sin(y)}{\cosh(x)-\cos(y)}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: How did you pass from the fifth line to the sixth line?

Comment: Jack, from the fifth to sixth lines, I multiplied the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator, which rendered the new denominator equal to the square of the magnitude of the original denominator.

Answer (score 1):

My hint would be that the easiest approach would be to use the defining formulae for $\sin$ and $\sinh$, and $\cos$ and $\cosh$ in terms of exponentials:
$$\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$$
etc.